# How to retrive data using hibernate in many-to-many associations

Tags: hibernate

I have been following this [tutorial][1]

[1]: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example I am able to save the data successfully.Now I have to retrieve the user data based on groups and the extra columns. For ex- Get the users with group='value' and registered_date='date value'

Can anybody guide me on the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userGroup.group_id.name AS groupName, userGroup.user_id.username AS username FROM user_group userGroup WHERE userGroup.user_id = 1 AND userGroup.group_id.name = 'someGroupName' AND userGroup.register_date = '2017 March 23 23:34:45'
```

Comment: Hi Anurag,Thank you for the response , i tried with the above query and it seems to give me only the username and grp name. However i was expecting something which would give me user object itself to further play with it.

Comment: SELECT userGroup.user_id FROM user_group userGroup WHERE userGroup.user_id = 1 AND userGroup.group_id.name = 'someGroupName' AND userGroup.register_date = '2017 March 23 23:34:45'